# How can I send an email 24 hours after first email?

Tags: email

I have an interesting question from a client, they want the ability to automatically send out an email 24 hours after the first email has been received.

The idea is we have a guide on our website that you enter your details name email etc and click download it then sends an email to the client,

but what they are wanting is that 24 hours after that email has been sent, another email sends out saying pretty much hope your enjoying your guide if you have any questions please let us know.

Is this possible via a plugin or a 3rd party mailer ?

Comment: You can use [cron jobs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by many ways. You can use wordpress cron job which has the function like wp_schedule_event(). Go through its documentation and you will get multiple arguments that can be passed through the function.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

Another way is use wordpress set_transient() and get_transient() function. please check their documenation for better understanding.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_transient
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_transient

Also there are many plugins, which can do this job easily.